# Magento2.4: Getting error while importing the product custom option

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, importexport

We have created the product custom options by uploading the csv file but its showing the error and the uploaded custom option is not showing in the frontend.

Getting the below error:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xyz`.`catalog_product_option`, CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_OPTION_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ROW_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`row_), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_option` (`product_id`, `type`, `is_require`, `sort_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) [] []
```

We're not sure why this error is appearing as we don't have any errors in other instances of our server. It would be great if anyone guide me to resolve this error.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Any duplicate record found into the csv file?